# Apache userdir + suEXEC + fcgid doesn't recognise dot separated useraccounts

Tags: linux, apache2.2, mod-fcgid, suexec

I've setup Apache with suEXEC, fcgid and userdir to enhance overall website security.

Everything works expect for useraccounts with a "." between their accountnames. Before using suEXEC and fcgid, this used to work although that practice has been discouraged many years ago.

For example:    mydomain.com/~mytest/    works
                mydomain.com/~my.test/   doesn't work

The error message that I get is "Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

Is there a quick workaround to this or I'm I doomed at recreating all the accounts without any accountname separation?

Answer (score 0):

Historically usernames were up to 8 characters long, started with a letter, and contained only lower case letters, underscore, and numbers.  Some systems still make this assumption, and that is probably what is catching you out here.